# How-To support Internationalization of JQuery Mobile Offline Web App (i18n)?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, internationalization, offline-mode

I am looking for a general mechanism to internationalize web application that have to work in offline mode.

Initially I was considering adding data-i18n tags to elements but this seems like a very ugly solution.

I came across http://panacodalabs.github.com/The-M-Docs/#components_&_utilities/m_i18n however I do not wish (or can due to time constrains) port my application to that framework.

I need a HTML5 jQuery Mobile friendly solution to this issue, that works in offline mode.

It seems to me that this crucial component is missing on the HTML5 framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily say this is a feature JQM should provide, because this is probably done best with some server side logic.

there would be two ways I can think of doing this:
1. have all your language translations in some standalone js files, which you would have to include in manifest file. check the [datebox plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox) to see how this could be done ( top right - options).
2. create a local database and store translations in the required languages there.

i think the first one should be easier to handle, but probably harder to setup/maintain. also, depending on the amount of translations, js files do become large...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As you know more and more web apps are expected to work offline, so we need to start relying less and less on server side to solve certain issues like internationalization.

I think that ill have to hack something up... The M project provides internationalization out of the box, but I don't want to rely on that framework it's pure js and I don't have time to learn their application of the mvc pattern.

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of tricky. I'm also working on a project in multiple langauges and am not really sure, how to get it offline (well... need to get it online first...). Right now I'm mixing javascript and server-side, but for offline, I'm not sure if I'd want to download a full language table, because as you say, these tend to get big. For simple stuff like form validation texts, I'm ok with dropping a javascript array-snippets with relevant texts into the page, which when stored offline would be available. Not perfect though.

Comment: I looked at Datebox again. If you check here: http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/ in the source code, I think the per language setup is very nice. So you would have a .js file per language and maybe have the user decide which one they want to have avaialbel offline. If you hack something, I'd almost recommend going this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the jQuery i18n plugin?

http://recursive-design.com/projects/jquery-i18n/

I'm currently using it with jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.1.0, and it works perfectly.

Comment: i don't see how this is helpful at all. Create a JSON dictionary for each language in an JS-file and include the variables where the text should be. Then switch between the JS files for changing the language. That's my solution. I don't see how that plugin can help - could you elaborate?